# Entity Framework 4 - Navigation Property Object Null on Client Side

Tags: entity-framework

There are two tables of interest in my entity conceptual model: tblProducts and tblInstalledProducts.

Each installed product has a ProductID foreign key linking it to a specific product, which was set up automatically as a navigation property.

Within the entity domain service I have the following query:

```
public IQueryable<tblInstalledProduct> GetInstalledProductsBySiteID(string SiteID)
{
    ObjectSet<tblInstalledProduct> installedProducts = this.ObjectContext.tblInstalledProducts;

    var filterBySite =
        from p in installedProducts.Include("tblProduct")
        where p.SiteID == SiteID
        select p;

    return filterBySite;
}
```

I have a DataGridView bound to a DomainDataSource configured to use this query.

When I debug this query, p.tblProduct and p.tblProductReference are populated as expected.  The problem arises when trying to access the tblProduct property of any tblInstalledProduct from the client side.

```
//Find associated install record for the selected product
tblInstalledProduct selectedInstall =
    Context.tblInstalledProducts.Where(
        p => p.SiteID == "Site1" && p.ProductID == 38
    ).First();

    string productName = selectedInstall.tblProduct.ProductName;
```

For some reason tblProduct is always null.  I've tried .Include() / .Load() and can't seem to get it to populate itself.

Why is tblInstalledProduct.tblProduct loaded up as expected on the service side of things, but is seemingly inaccessible on the client side?

Thanks for reading.

Edit:

XAML DataSource:

```
<telerik:RadDomainDataSource x:Key="InstalledProductsDataSource"
         Name="InstalledProductsDataSource"
         DomainContext="{StaticResource DomainContext}" 
         AutoLoad="True" 
         QueryName="GetInstalledProductsInfoBySiteID"
         SubmittedChanges="InstalledProductsDataSource_SubmittedChanges">
    <telerik:RadDomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
        <telerik:QueryParameter
                ParameterName="SiteID" 
                Value="{Binding SelectedValue,ElementName=SiteList}" />
    </telerik:RadDomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
</telerik:RadDomainDataSource>
```

XAML DataGrid:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="InstalledProductsGridView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataView, Source={StaticResource InstalledProductsDataSource}}">

    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Product Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Version" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ProductVersion, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Right now the grid is bound to a collection of tblProducts, but I'd like to bind it to a collection of tblInstalledProducts (as there is some extra information in that table that I need access to) like so:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="DateInstalled" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DateInstalled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Product Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding tblProduct.ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Version" DataMemberBinding="{Binding tblProduct.ProductVersion, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding tblProduct.Description, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

Comment: *"I've tried .Include()"* - So `Context.tblInstalledProducts.Include("tblProduct")
.Where(` doesn't work?

Comment: why you didn't call GetInstalledProductsBySiteID in the client side?

Comment: @BlueRaja: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntitySet<MyProject.Web.tblInstalledProduct>' does not contain a definition for 'Include'

@Waleed: I'm using that query for binding the DataGridView, and it is returning a populated tblInstalledProduct record with a null tblProduct reference.  I haven't tried calling it asynchronously from the code-behind, but I'm positive it would return the same thing in both cases (and I'm not completely sure how to do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having problems with this, I did eventually find the solution.  You need to use both .Include() on the query to tell it to load related objects, as well as the [Include] attribute in the metadata to allow those related objects to be serialized and sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this

```
 tblInstalledProduct selectedInstall = Context.GetInstalledProductsBySiteID("Site1").Where(p=> p.ProductID == 38 ).FirstOrDefault();
        string productName="";
        if(selectedInstall !=null)
        {
            productName= selectedInstall.tblProduct.ProductName;
        }
```

for testing try to use;

```
public IQueryable<tblInstalledProduct> GetInstalledProductsNew()
        {
            //Im nut Sure of 'tblProduct' or 'tblProducts' it is dependent on your relations
            return this.ObjectContext.tblInstalledProducts.Include("tblProduct");
        }
```

Comment: Doing that yields the following error: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery<MyProject.Web.tblProduct>' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Comment: After adding 'using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client' it now says `does not contain a definition for 'First'`

Comment: After adding `Context.Load(Context.GetTblProductsQuery());` to the constructor it seems queries are now working as expected.  For some reason the tblInstalledProduct objects stored in the DataGrid still have null tblProducts though (if I iterate through DataGrid.Items and cast the rows to tblInstalledProducts).  I thought this might be a result of binding the data before the async. Context.Load call had completed, but it seems even an explicit deferred load on the DomainDataSource still ends up with null tblProducts.

Comment: Because GetTblProductsQuery() doesn't have include in it, use GetInstalledProductsBySiteID insted

Comment: use temporary:
public IQueryable<tblInstalledProduct> GetInstalledProductsNew()
        {
            //Im nut Sure of 'tblProduct' or 'tblProducts' it is dependent on your relations
            return this.ObjectContext.tblInstalledProducts.Include("tblProduct");
        }

Comment: _Because GetTblProductsQuery() doesn't have include in it, use GetInstalledProductsBySiteID instead_ I'm not sure what you meant by this.  Loading GetTblProductsQuery() in the constructor fixed all queries in the code, and I don't have access to a SiteID in the constructor so I can't use GetInstalledProductsBySiteID() instead.  I'm trying to fix the fact that the tblInstalledProduct's which are bound to the datagrid are missing a properly instantiated tblProduct property.